# Cocos2d - cassert file not found

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am getting this error while trying to compile my Cocos2d application. I know this usually happens when you forget to name source files with the .mm extension. I did make that mistake. So I renamed my new source files to include the .mm extension, performed a clean, and then tried to rebuild.

Can someone suggest the fix? The new source files are of type Objective-C++. Not sure what else to try.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I had to check that each .mm source file was of type "Objective-C++ Source". All but one of my source files were. So if you accidentally add a source file with the ".m" extension and then subsequently rename it, double check that the type is set to "Objective-C++ Source in the right pane. It should look like the attached.

[image]

Hope this helps someone else would is pounding their head against a wall ;)

Comment: Yeah this was a fun one to encounter had the same issue couple months ago sorry I didn't see this sooner!  Glad you solved it.